# Adding entry for an i2c device connected on i2c mux in linux device tree

Tags: linux, embedded, linux-device-driver, device-tree

I am using freescale powerpc 85xx processor with linux 2.6.32.
 The i2c subsytem is mapped at address 0x03000 inside the ccsr registers.  I want to add an **RTC device**,DS1338 (i2c addr: **0x68**) connected to an I2c mux (address: **0x76**) on channel 5 (selected by writing **0xfd** on control register).
Without adding the device in the dts file, the rtc device won't bind to driver.
I have the following entry in my device tree right now:

```
i2c@3000 {  /* I2C 1 */
             #address-cells = <1>;
             #size-cells = <0>;
             cell-index = <0>;
             compatible = "fsl-i2c";
             reg = <0x3000 0x100>;
             interrupts = <43 2>;
             interrupt-parent = <&mpic>;
             dfsrr;

         };
```

What would it look like after adding the above information. Had it been a device directly on the i2c bus and not through mux, I would have added something like this:

```
  i2c@3000 {  /* I2C 1 */
                 #address-cells = <1>;
                 #size-cells = <0>;
                 cell-index = <0>;
                 compatible = "fsl-i2c";
                 reg = <0x3000 0x100>;
                 interrupts = <43 2>;
                 interrupt-parent = <&mpic>;

                 rtc:rtc@68 {
                  compatible = "dallas,ds1307";
                  reg = <0x68>;
                 };

                 dfsrr;

             };
```

Now with the mux in the path, and having to select channel, I don't think I know how to make an entry.

Comment: I thought of 2 workarounds to this issue 1st would be to select the appropriate  channel from uboot, let the kernel boot and see the rtc device (which is now visible at address 0x68 as I entered in the device tree). 2nd would be to compile the driver separately and insert it later after boot-up (after I have selected appropriate channel from userspace).

Comment: The downside of both the cases is that if anytime I have to use rtc my application will have to select the channel and then only invoke the "hwclock" command. So I would rather have the kernel know where exactly my i2c is and do it for me.

Comment: I have used the 1st method. It works just fine. I am really looking forward to making appropriate entry in device tree rather than this though, ofcourse for the reasons mentioned in 2nd comment.

Comment: This is an exemple of a proper dts for a platform using an i2c mux: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/arm/boot/dts/imx28-cfa10049.dts#L216